# how to count value of last column in repeater control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, asprepeater

Look at the  below picture I want to count value of last column (cnt) I am using repeater control.

**example:**

```
if (last column (cnt) is greater than 5> )
{
    response.write ("6");
}
```

**sql query**

[image]

```
 SELECT id, category, ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entry_table WHERE category.id = entry_table.Cat_id) as cnt FROM category
```

**Repeater code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CloudTags" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="CloudTags_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server">
             <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Category")%>
            (<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.cnt")%>)
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void CloudTags_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: why not simply `<%# ((int) Eval("cnt")) > 5 ? "6" : string.Empty %>`?

Comment: can u hints little bit more.....plz

Comment: this ain't no hint, this is the solution ... what exact problem do you have?

Comment: actually i want to count value of last column (cnt). 
i am trying to get value of last column (cnt) as a integer. 

example : 


if ( last column (cnt) > 5)
                {
HyperLink HyperLink9 = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink9");

 HyperLink9.CssClass = "TagSize2";
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
protected void CloudTags_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var repeaterItem = e.Item;
    // TODO you still have to check the type of the repeaterItem
    var dataItem = (dynamic) repeaterItem.DataItem;
    var cnt = dataItem.cnt;
    if (cnt > 5)
    {
        var hyperLink = (HyperLink) repeaterItem.FindControl("HyperLink9");
        hyperLink.CssClass = "TagSize2";
    }
}
```

or

```
protected void CloudTags_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var repeaterItem = e.Item;
    // TODO you still have to check the type of the repeaterItem
    var dataItem = repeaterItem.DataItem;
    var objCnt = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "cnt");
    // TODO check the whole parsing/converting stuff ...
    var stringCnt = objCnt.toString();
    var cnt = int.Parse(stringCnt);
    if (cnt > 5)
    {
        var hyperLink = (HyperLink) repeaterItem.FindControl("HyperLink9");
        hyperLink.CssClass = "TagSize2";
    }
}
```

Anyway, I strongly suggest you to not use `dynamic` or `DataBinder.Eval` and rather cast the `.Data`-property to a strong type! Otherwise, this will cause some fancy runtime reflection and will have an impact on the performance!

Comment: glad to help! you could however, if this answer fits you, tick this one as solution ;)